# MVC logic for Android application

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, view, model

I would to write an Android application for detect object in a video frame obtained from an Parrot Ar Drone. I've choose to use an MVC pattern for this purpose, when the Model contains the drone status (if is flying, the new videoframe, the navigation data, etc.).

For detect an object (a ball for be specific) I've decided to filter the image on the hue value of the object to detect and then apply the Huogh Circle Transform by OpenCV.
For obtain color on which toich to apply the hue filter, I would create a calibration activity, that calculate the histogram of the object in front of the drone's camera and, when a button is pressed, this histogram is set in the model and a new activity (so a new view that visualize the object detected. We call this a detection view) is started.

Where I must calcute the histogram? In the view, by getting the videoframe from the model or in the model when the new videoframe arrived from the drone?

And where I must run the detection algorithm? In the detection view or in the model?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can call your Activities the 'control' layer in MVC. 
You want to keep the logic in your Activities (and Fragments) to a minimum, since although Activities and Fragments are re-usable as a whole, partial logic inside of it isn't.

Calculations such as detecting an object in an image or video, I wouldn't put inside a Model-object, since that should be much more like a POJO, just holding on to data. 
I'd personally create some Util class for this, which will behave as a class in your Model layer.

Re-calculating into a custom visualization, sounds more like a custom View. 
This View can have logic, but only the one used to present itself. All data should be given to it, not fetched. The real logic should just be the View drawing itself.